# Most efficient way to convert BCD to binary

Tags: c#, binary, bcd

I have the code below to convert a 32 bit BCD value (supplied in two uint halves) to a uint binary value.

The values supplied can be up to 0x9999, to form a maximum value of 0x99999999.

Is there a better (ie. quicker) way to achieve this?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert two PLC words in BCD format (forming 8 digit number) into single binary integer.
    /// e.g. If Lower = 0x5678 and Upper = 0x1234, then Return is 12345678 decimal, or 0xbc614e.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lower">Least significant 16 bits.</param>
    /// <param name="upper">Most significant 16 bits.</param>
    /// <returns>32 bit unsigned integer.</returns>
    /// <remarks>If the parameters supplied are invalid, returns zero.</remarks>
    private static uint BCD2ToBin(uint lower, uint upper)
    {
        uint binVal = 0;

        if ((lower | upper) != 0)
        {
            int shift = 0;
            uint multiplier = 1;
            uint bcdVal = (upper << 16) | lower;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                uint digit = (bcdVal >> shift) & 0xf;

                if (digit > 9)
                {
                    binVal = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    binVal += digit * multiplier;
                    shift += 4;
                    multiplier *= 10;
                }
            }
        }

        return binVal;
    }
```

Comment: Looks pretty damn good to me.

Comment: Why does it take two uints rather than ushorts, if each one only represents 16 bits?

Comment: Don Knuth gives a 3-line version as the answer to an exercise in Volume 2 of *The Art of Computer Programming.* Much more efficient than anything here so far.

Comment: Specifically, it is the answer to #4-4, exercise 19. I am voting to reopen this question. I fail to see how a question asking for the most efficient algorithm can possibly be opninion-based. Really some of the closures here are appalling.

Answer (score 8):

If you've space to spare for a 39,322 element array, you could always just look the value up.

Comment: For raw speed a look-up table is certainly going to win.

Comment: The quickest solution so far. (he asked for it)

Comment: @GvS Memory access is slow, compared to most computations. Thus, LUTs can be slow if they're not in the cache.

Comment: @Simon 15 years ago most PLC's didn't have cache

Answer (score 7):

If you unroll the loop, remember to keep the bit shift.

```
value =  ( lo        & 0xF);
value += ((lo >> 4 ) & 0xF) * 10;
value += ((lo >> 8 ) & 0xF) * 100;
value += ((lo >> 12) & 0xF) * 1000;
value += ( hi        & 0xF) * 10000;
value += ((hi >> 4 ) & 0xF) * 100000;
value += ((hi >> 8 ) & 0xF) * 1000000;
value += ((hi >> 12) & 0xF) * 10000000;
```

Comment: This should be combined with AShelly's answer

Comment: Please put parens around the bit twiddling operators - the operator precedence for them is very confusing for most people.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems rather complicated; do you require the specific error checking?

Otherwise, you could just use the following code which shouldn't be slower, in fact, it's mostly the same:

```
uint result = 0;
uint multiplier = 1;
uint value = lo | hi << 0x10;

while (value > 0) {
    uint digit = value & 0xF;
    value >>= 4;
    result += multiplier * digit;
    multiplier *= 10;
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could unroll the loop:

```
value = ( lo     & 0xF);
value+= ((lo>>4) & 0xF) *10;
value+= ((lo>>8) & 0xF) *100;
value+= ((lo>>12)& 0xF) *1000;
value+= ( hi     & 0xF) *10000;
value+= ((hi>>4  & 0xF) *100000;
value+= ((hi>>8) & 0xF) *1000000;
value+= ((hi>>12)& 0xF) *10000000;
```

And you can check for invalid BCD digits like this:

```
invalid = lo & ((lo&0x8888)>>2)*3
```

This sets invalid to a non-zero value if any single hex digit > 9.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. When you unroll the loop, you have to remember the "value >>= 4;"

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it

```
uint8_t bcd_to_int(uint8_t * inBuf, uint8_t inLen)     // Input buffer of inLen bytes.
{
while(inLen--)
    {
    uint8_t vTmp = *inBuf;
    if ( (vTmp > 0x99) || ((vTmp&0x0F) > 0x09) )
        {
        return ERROR;
        }
    // simplification of (vTmp>>4)*10 + (vTmp&0x0F)
    //                 = (vTmp>>4)*10 + vTmp - (vTmp&0xF0)
    //                 = (vTmp>>4)*10 + vTmp - (vTmp>>4)*16
    //                 =                vTmp - (vTmp>>4)*6
    *inBuf++ = vTmp-(vTmp>>4)*6;
    }
return OK;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static int bcd2int(int bcd) {
   return int.Parse(bcd.ToString("X"));
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not the most efficient way the OP was asking for. One of the reasons is that it allocates a string object as part of the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static uint BCDToNum(int num)
{
    return uint.Parse(num.ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not the most efficient way the OP was asking for. One of the reasons is that it allocates a string object as part of the conversion.

Comment: @Simon I agree. I really don't remember why I posted this answer 12 years ago. But I think this is because I've understood "most efficient" as simpler in terms of code complexity, not the performance.

Answer (score -2):

Of course, there are a more efficient method. this is just a example of course, so you can tune it as a lesson ^^

```
function bcd_to_bin ($bcd) {    
$mask_sbb = 0x33333333;         
$mask_msb = 0x88888888;
$mask_opp = 0xF;

for($i=28;$i;--$i) {            
    $mask_msb <<= 1;
    $mask_opp <<= 1;
    $mask_sbb <<= 1;

    for($j=0;$j<$i;$j+=4) { 
        $mask_opp_j = $mask_opp << $j;

        if ($bcd & $mask_msb & $mask_opp_j ) {
            $bcd -= $mask_sbb & $mask_opp_j;
        }
    }
}

return $bcd;
```

}